# nmcli - all connections show "unmanaged"

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I searched for an answer to this and found a few different things but none of them have resolved my problem.

On a fresh install of 22.04.1 (server - no DE)...

`nmcli con show` returns an empty line. (likewise `sudo nmcli con show`)

`nmcli -v` returns "nmcli tool, version 1.36.6".

`nmcli -o d` returns:

```
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
docker0  bridge    unmanaged  --         
enp1s0   ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo       loopback  unmanaged  --
```

`nmcli d show enp1s0` returns:

```
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.10.10.121/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.10.10.1
```

I've run update/upgrade. And rebooted. I've tried restarting NetworkManager. And rebooting again. No joy.

Help?

Comment: Networking on a server is usually managed by netplan, not Network Manager. In fact, NM is not installed on servers by default. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.